# Android How can make toolbar title and subtitle have touch effect?

Tags: android, toolbar

This image capture form whatsapp, how can i do that?

[I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jslGE.jpg)

[It's my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YjVI.jpg)

and my code

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
mToolbar.setTitle("Subject");
mToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }
});
mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back);
mToolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Log.i("ChatActivity", "Back");
        onBackPressed();
    }
});
```

In my app, only navigation icon part have touch effect, then i touch on title part, it no touch effect.

Comment: please provide more details about your problem and your efforts for this problem.

Comment: check if this helps -- http://guides.codepath.com/android/ripple-animation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
 1. Create a new layout called 'my_toolbar' for instance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_custom_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content""/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

2. include this layout in your activity layout.
3. in onCreate(...), find your toolbar view, and in it find your TextView and apply an onClickListener on it

   mToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

   ```
   if (mToolBar != null) {
       setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);
   }

   super.setTitle("");
   mTitleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_custom_title);
   mTitleTextView.setOnClickListener(...);
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You can edit actionbar.

```
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

if it doesnt work, you can try this. So you can put image in titlebar.

```
   getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);
   getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

if you want to get image click, u can get from optionsitemselected like that

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case android.R.id.home:
                //do something
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing OP is asking for the ripple effect that's seen in the toolbar.

Comment: Thx for reply~
Yes, i don't know why title part haven't ripple effect, need any setting to do?

Comment: yes, i did it, i don't know why whatsapp tap title part can have touch effect and go in another page, no difficult it's full custom toolbar...